# No internet through GSM connection, possible interface issue

Tags: interface, connection, ubuntu-18.04, gsm, networkmanager

I have a problem with getting GSM connection to work.

Currently used:

- Advantech UNO-2272G device
- Ubuntu 18.04
- NetworkManager/nmcli package

The card works when put in a mobile phone.

*Note: following screenshots are made over SSH and remotely, as the device is currently plugged in ethernet until this issue is resolved.

This is current state of "nmcli" command:

[nmcli print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1wWY.png)

The system connection for GSM is called "radi". My guess is that somehow the interface of that connection is trying to work with the other interface (underlined in red), which in turn is trying to get its DNS conf from router (to which it currently is connected with ethernet, but nothing changes if device is plugged out from router and NetworkManager and network is restarted, it still tries to get to router for its DNS).

This is current state of "ip addr" command:

[ip addr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7jpE.png)

This is current state of /etc/network/interfaces file:

[interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9yqg.png)

This is current state of /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/radi file:

[systemconnection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38M4L.png)

So, the question is, what am I missing here? Is it the interface issue as written above, or something else entirely?

Disclaimer: I am not that proficient in the stuff presented here, most if not all of it was configured following guidelines on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm not expert in this but I do have a different cellular modem connected to a linux system (RPI) and working with NetworkManager (and ModemManager). My modem was connected by a serial UART port (ttyACM0) so that seems similar to what you have done.

When I configured my cellular connection profile in NM I had to setup the ppp section of the connection profile on top of the gsm part. I also went into my ppp options (on the host) and configured those to match a chat script that came from my modem manufacturer. WHen NetworkManager runs a ppp interface it expects the ppp options for the pppd (daemon) to be configured properly.

Here is the ppp section of my NetworkManager cellular connection settings file. Most are defaults and in my case I only added the baud rate for my modem (since it was connected to a UART).

```
ppp.noauth:                             yes
ppp.refuse-eap:                         no
ppp.refuse-pap:                         no
ppp.refuse-chap:                        no
ppp.refuse-mschap:                      no
ppp.refuse-mschapv2:                    no
ppp.nobsdcomp:                          no
ppp.nodeflate:                          no
ppp.no-vj-comp:                         no
ppp.require-mppe:                       no
ppp.require-mppe-128:                   no
ppp.mppe-stateful:                      no
ppp.crtscts:                            no
ppp.baud:                               115200
ppp.mru:                                0
ppp.mtu:                                auto
ppp.lcp-echo-failure:                   0
ppp.lcp-echo-interval:                  0
```

If this is not helpful then have a look at [this thread on NM and routing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203284/networkmanager-changes-default-routing-policy). In their case eth0 was a local network interface and eth1 was their cellular interface

> Now to save you 10 hours of troubleshooting - note that the route
>   metric is independent of the DNS priority! So if you still have
>   connectivity issues, make sure it's not a DNS resolution issue (eg.
>   your DHCP server is providing a dummy resolution service). If it is,
>   then increase the ipv4.dns-priority of your eth0 connection to make it
>   lower priority, and/or make sure the ipv4.dns-search of your eth1 is
>   set to "~" to make it the go-to option.